# How to remove colon in a label which is not in a form - D6

Tags: theming

How can I remove colon from the labels which is not in a form?

If it is a form, `themename_form_element()` can be used, but my question isn't related to forms.

For example, I need to remove colons from the profile view page. How can I do that?

I would like to do this the "Drupal way" (meaning not using JavaScript/jQuery)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drupal 6 or Drupal 7? The Drupal way to do this would be to modify the content field template in your theme to remove the colon OR create a custom node template to render the fields without the colon. For the content-field option, in Drupal 6 this file is in your cck folder under:

./modules/cck/theme/content-field.tpl.php

Copy this file to your themes folder and modify it to remove the colon at line 18:

```
<div class="field-label"><?php print t($label) ?>:&nbsp;</div>
```

For a node template, check out the handbook on node templates, theming, etc:

http://drupal.org/node/190815#node-suggestion

There's also this module

http://drupal.org/project/no_colons

if you want another alternative.